# problem of robotium

Tags: android, robotium

I just start to use robotium. The demo can be run without any problem, but when I wrote first test script by using `EditText` and `Button`, problems occured. My environment is android 2.1 and the script is quite simple, just input username and psw, then click sumbit button to login.
The script is as follows:

```
package com.tpc.test;

import com.tpc.login.Login;
import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.Smoke;

public class LoginTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Login>{

    private Solo solo;

    public LoginTest() {
        super("com.tpc", Login.class);

    }

     public void setUp() throws Exception {
         solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
          }


     @Smoke
     public void testApp() throws Exception {
         String appName = solo.getCurrentActivity().getClass().getSimpleName();
         System.out.println(appName);
         solo.getButton(0).getClass().getSimpleName();
         solo.assertCurrentActivity("Expected login activity", appName); 
                 System.out.println(solo.getButton(0).getText());//can get the text of button
         solo.enterText(0, "name"); //input name to the 1st EditText is OK
         solo.enterText(1, "psw");   // Actually inout psw after name to the 1st EditText
         solo.clickOnButton(0);       //Expect click the 1st button.Actually click the 1st EditText
         //assert of sample, not been modified      
         boolean expected = true;
         boolean actual = solo.searchText("Note 1") && solo.searchText("Note 2");
         assertEquals("Note 1 and/or Note 2 are not found", false, actual);
     }

    @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        try {
            solo.finalize();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        getActivity().finish();
        super.tearDown();
    } 
}
```

One problem is both name and psw is filled in the first `EditText`,the other is `solo.clickOnButton(0);` click the first `EditText`, NOT the first `Button`. I also tried to use the text name of the `Button`, but the result was the same. It seems all the operations been put to the first `EditText`. I wanna what's the problem. Any suggestion?thanks

Comment: This is what i have written to solve this issue. http://chanakaudaya.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/robotium-button-click-not-working-solution

Answer (score 5):

I have had a look at the application that you want to test and the problem is that you do not state that it supports high density screens. That gives Robotium problems as you are using it on a high density emulator/device.

You need to add the following tag in the AndroidManifest.xml:

`<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"/>`

If you add that tag to your AndroidManifest.xml then it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Hope you are taking the enter text as a array.. 0 and 1..

But hope you didn't initialize the array

```
import java.util.Arraylist;
```

Hope it will work if you initialize the arraylist. Have a try.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to add this tag to your AndroidManifest.xml:

`<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="7"/>` where 7 means Android 2.1.

If that does not work then please post this on the robotium developers page and I will have a look at it.

http://groups.google.com/group/robotium-developers

Sincerely,
Renas

Comment: Dear Renas,
Sorry, I cannot open this link

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and i couldn’t find a solution with robotium. Then i move to the android instrumentation provided with the SDK. What i have done is mentioned below. This worked without any issues for me. Here it is ..

First define a private variable for the button as a member variable

```
private Button msButton;
```

Then get the button instance with in the setup method.

```
mButton = (Button) solo.getCurrentActivity().findViewById(
com.marakana.android.simple_intent.R.id.sendButton);
```

Then call the button click with in the UI thread in the test method as mentioned below.

```
//Test button method

public void testButtonClick() {

//Get the current activity and request to run onUI thread
solo.getCurrentActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

public void run() { 

//Request focus for the button
mButton.requestFocus();
}
});

//Send the button click event
this.sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER);

}
```

That’s it .. Now you can test your button with other Robotium features.